# find the department that has the most efficient team (the team with the minimum percentage of employees who need training)

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# The file is stored at the following path:
# 'https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/NMgEjwkAEGGQZBoNYGr9Ld7w0/rating.csv'
df = pd.read_csv('https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/NMgEjwkAEGGQZBoNYGr9Ld7w0/rating.csv')
df['Training'] = df.Rating.apply(lambda x : 'No' if x <= 3.5 else 'Yes')
df.head()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly?

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/NMgEjwkAEGGQZBoNYGr9Ld7w0/rating.csv')

df = (
    df
    .groupby("Department")["Rating"]
    .mean()
    .reset_index()
    .min()["Department"]
)

print(df)

Finance
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in ['Finance', 'HR', 'Sales', 'Marketing']:
    print(i, len(rating[(rating['Training'] == 'No') & (rating['Department'] == i)]) / len(rating[rating['Department'] == i]) * 100)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think your column assignment is wrong. should be:
df['Training'] = df['Rating'].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x <= 3.5 else 'No')

Then you create new dataframe with only employees needing training, then perform count per department
df_2 = df[df['Training'] == 'Yes']
df_2.groupby('Department').count()

Compare the results and answer should be HR